# C System() takes control of stdout

Tags: c

I'm writing a program in C, in this model:

```
//Block 1: Does a lot of operations, including debug messages

strcpy(call, "xdg-open ");
strcat(call, url);

system(call);

//Block 2: Does a lot of operations, including debug messages
```

After the invocation of `system()`, it looks like this function takes control of stdout and Block 2 debug messages aren't printed anylonger, only Block 1 messages.

Does anybody know what is happening and what might be the solution for it?

Comment: The `system` call waits for its subprocess to end. Said differently, the control will only be passed to block2 when `xdg-open` will be closed.

Comment: I understand now, but how can I solve that "problem"?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute some other application using `int system(const char *command)` function, your application will wait until the called one exits. That is the reason why you do not see any outputs from `Block 2`.

You could solve this by adding `&` at the end off command which will cause whole application will run as different process. So you can try this:

```
strcpy(call, "xdg-open ");
strcat(call, url);
strcat(call, " &");

system(call);
```

Also you may need to flush `stdout` buffer, so call `fflush(stdout)` after `Block 2`.

Comment: Doing the same result, I've tried that before. It seems the command's execution finishes but stdout remains with the same.

Comment: Try to call `fflush(stdout)` after printing debug messages.

Comment: It solves the problem temporarily, but this is one function of a very complex program, its annoying having to do that to print the debug messages.

Comment: This is just feature of `stdout`. You can always define your own debugging function which will flush buffer after every single debug message.  See this if you want to know more about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin